# Short url of a specific wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, share, permalinks

How to see the short url (or default permalink) of a specific wordpress post (which is using pretty permalink now). Im simply a visitor. 
I want to see "short url" just for sharing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how the theme is created,

if you view the source code for that page, it could have the ID number assosiated with that post applied as a class or div id.

ie:

```
<div id="post-2311" class="post-2311 post status-publish format-standard category-news" >
```

here you can see that post-2311 is the id for the DIV, this will be using the wordpress $post->ID in the template, you can use this ID number to generate the short url to that page.

```
ie: http://thewebsite.com/?p=2311
```

using that link will direct you to the post, but replace the querysting with the nice url.

M